# Socket Write Error in a Spring-boot application

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, amazon-rds

I've created a **spring-boot** application and it's hosted in Amazon EC2.

The problem seems to be with a experired connection with MySQL database.

**After some idle time the error below happens, and my webservice returns error 500.**

I would like to know if there's a **configuration property** that I could add to **avoid this error**.

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.TransactionException: JDBC begin transaction failed: 
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.doBegin(JdbcTransaction.java:76)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.begin(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:162)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beginTransaction(SessionImpl.java:1431)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.TransactionImpl.begin(TransactionImpl.java:61)
    ... 66 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: The last packet successfully received from the server was57961 seconds ago.The last packet sent successfully to the server was 57961 seconds ago, which  is longer than the server configured value of 'wait_timeout'. You should consider either expiring and/or testing connection validity before use in your application, increasing the server configured values for client timeouts, or using the Connector/J connection property 'autoReconnect=true' to avoid this problem.
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:406)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1074)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.send(MysqlIO.java:3246)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1917)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2060)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2536)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.setAutoCommit(ConnectionImpl.java:4874)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ProxyConnection.invoke(ProxyConnection.java:126)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.JdbcInterceptor.invoke(JdbcInterceptor.java:109)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DisposableConnectionFacade.invoke(DisposableConnectionFacade.java:80)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy42.setAutoCommit(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.doBegin(JdbcTransaction.java:72)
    ... 69 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: socket write error
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
```

My configuration properties have these properties so far:

```
spring.datasource.url=xxxx
spring.datasource.username=xxx
spring.datasource.password=xxxx
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
server.port=80
spring.datasource.time-between-eviction-runs-millis=10000
spring.datasource.min-evictable-idle-time-millis=10000
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you check the javadocs for the `DataSource` that you are using. If it's the Tomcat `DataSource` which is the default if it's on the classpath, you can set

`spring.datasource.validationQuery=SELECT 1
spring.datasource.testOnBorrow=true`

(for instance). Other data source implementations have similar properties and Spring Boot just binds to them via `spring.datasource.*`.

Comment: is that behaviour documented somewhere? The reference manual has properties like `spring.datasource.max-idle=8`, but I'm not seeing that passthrough behaviour documented anywhere (nor is it obvious how that works in `DataSourceAutoConfiguration`).

Comment: Both those properties are listed in the latest guide (http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#common-application-properties). If the passthru feature is not obvious please raise a documentation issue in github.